# Breakpoints no longer stops after upgrading an ActiveX server (for MS Word) from Delphi 7 to Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I have a Word addin (an **ActiveX** server (**DLL**)) developed with Addin Express VCL, after upgrading the entire project from D7 to XE4, I found that the breakpoints are no longer stable - sometimes the breakpoints stop, but most of the time they do NOT.

I've tried all the solutions in other questions (as shown on the first and two pages of Google results for this search query: `delphi breakpoint does not work site:stackoverflow.com`), but none of them worked. Any help? Thanks.

**Update 1:** Things I've tried:

- Ensure the build configuration is 'debug';
- Rebuild the entire project;
- The 'Debug information' project option is enabled;
- The 'Local symbols' project option is enabled;
- Linking-> Debug information is enabled;
- 'Remote debugging' is enabled';

---

**Update 2:** Very strange, after enabled 'use debug dcus', rebuilt, disabled it again, rebuilt, now I'm getting the following error. IE, the breakpoint works for the first time, then with some unexpected stops at the CPU window, terminated MS Word (the host), and trying to start debugging will cause the following error, and the IDE has to be started. **But when there is no problem when not in debug mode**

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Assertion failure: "!"could not initialize evaluator""
in ..\win32src\eval32.cpp at line 1231

---------------------------
OK   Details <<   
---------------------------
[2039534C]{dbkdebugide180.bpl} Debug.TDebugKernel.msgBox (Line 5931, "Debug.pas" + 30) + $0
[2E027FA9]{bordbk180.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $E0D1
[0DBAA4CC]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $2F654
[0DB7C6BF]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $1847
[080A4124]{dcc32180.dll} C:\BUILDS\TP\INTERMEDIATE\DEBUG\LIB\DCC32\CODEGEN.OBJ.FlushConst + $2170
[080A4D26]{dcc32180.dll} C:\BUILDS\TP\INTERMEDIATE\DEBUG\LIB\DCC32\CODEGEN.OBJ.FlushConst + $2D72
[0067FA5D]{bds.exe     } bds.bds (Line 204, "" + 8) + $19C49E
[080A4D26]{dcc32180.dll} C:\BUILDS\TP\INTERMEDIATE\DEBUG\LIB\DCC32\CODEGEN.OBJ.FlushConst + $2D72
[080B164A]{dcc32180.dll} C:\BUILDS\TP\INTERMEDIATE\DEBUG\LIB\DCC32\CODEGEN.OBJ.GenPackageBody + $116
[080AF6D3]{dcc32180.dll} C:\BUILDS\TP\INTERMEDIATE\DEBUG\LIB\DCC32\CODEGEN.OBJ.FlushConst + $D71F
[07F9130B]{dcc32180.dll} C:\BUILDS\TP\LIB\WIN32\DEBUG\C0D32W.OBJ.___System__GetTls + $11
[080B1AD4]{dcc32180.dll} C:\BUILDS\TP\INTERMEDIATE\DEBUG\LIB\DCC32\CODEGEN.OBJ.GenIntfAdjustor + $398
[080A4124]{dcc32180.dll} C:\BUILDS\TP\INTERMEDIATE\DEBUG\LIB\DCC32\CODEGEN.OBJ.FlushConst + $2170
[07FA4413]{dcc32180.dll} C:\BUILDS\TP\INTERMEDIATE\DEBUG\LIB\DCC32\BROWCMGR.OBJ.DumpSymtabUnitListLast + $BF
[080A3616]{dcc32180.dll} C:\BUILDS\TP\INTERMEDIATE\DEBUG\LIB\DCC32\CODEGEN.OBJ.FlushConst + $1662
[080A1C03]{dcc32180.dll} C:\BUILDS\TP\INTERMEDIATE\DEBUG\LIB\DCC32\CODEGEN.OBJ.ReserveConstructorFrameSlots + $140B
[0808D5A1]{dcc32180.dll} C:\BUILDS\TP\INTERMEDIATE\DEBUG\LIB\DCC32\LNK2DISK.OBJ.LocateLocalSymbols + $97D
[07FA8BBA]{dcc32180.dll} C:\BUILDS\TP\INTERMEDIATE\DEBUG\LIB\DCC32\BROWCMGR.OBJ.SetCompState + $FA
[07FA87E1]{dcc32180.dll} C:\BUILDS\TP\INTERMEDIATE\DEBUG\LIB\DCC32\BROWCMGR.OBJ.ClosePackageFilesDLL + $11D
[07FA8809]{dcc32180.dll} C:\BUILDS\TP\INTERMEDIATE\DEBUG\LIB\DCC32\BROWCMGR.OBJ.ClosePackageFilesDLL + $145
[0DB90C9F]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $15E27
[57008381]{madBasic_.bpl} Madstrings.WideToAnsiEx + $2D
[570114D4]{madBasic_.bpl} Madtools.FindModule + $C8
[57011500]{madBasic_.bpl} Madtools.FindModule + $F4
[5005FA84]{rtl180.bpl  } System.TMonitor.TryEnter (Line 17109, "System.pas" + 10) + $0
[5005F618]{rtl180.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Enter (Line 16808, "System.pas" + 4) + $2
[5005F7EB]{rtl180.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 16933, "System.pas" + 2) + $7
[0DBB1FCA]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at POSTEDHOOKPROC + $1246
[0DBB4EBB]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at POSTEDHOOKPROC + $4137
[0DBA3ED7]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $2905F
[0DBA3EE8]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $29070
[5981E15C]{madExcept_.bpl} Madexcept.IsTrueUnicodeString + $4BC
[5981E181]{madExcept_.bpl} Madexcept.IsTrueUnicodeString + $4E1
[5985A581]{madExcept_.bpl} Madexcept.UnpatchAPI + $801
[0DB90751]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $158D9
[5985A596]{madExcept_.bpl} Madexcept.UnpatchAPI + $816
[0DB90751]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $158D9
[0DB844DD]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $9665
[0DBAFB9D]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $34D25
[0DBADDE3]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $32F6B
[0DBADF23]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $330AB
[0DBA5D9E]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $2AF26
[0DBB4F27]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at POSTEDHOOKPROC + $41A3
(000083C9){bordbk180N.dll} [0DB793C9]
[0DB7C032]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $11BA
[0DB9B760]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $208E8
[504575B5]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 10039, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 153) + $6
[0DBB167F]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at POSTEDHOOKPROC + $8FB
[0DB9ADAC]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $1FF34
(00007EE1){bordbk180N.dll} [0DB78EE1]
[21101D7A]{designide180.bpl} DeskUtil.SetFocusHook (Line 463, "DeskUtil.pas" + 4) + $C
[218A45BB]{vclactnband180.bpl} Vcl.ActnMenus.CallWindowHook (Line 748, "Vcl.ActnMenus.pas" + 20) + $F
[0DB9C588]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $21710
[0DB9C56F]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $216F7
[0DB88656]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $D7DE
[0DB9C588]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $21710
[0DB7ED8A]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $3F12
[0DB9BC13]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $20D9B
[0DB9BEAD]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $21035
[0DB9D749]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $228D1
[0DBBF4DB]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at POSTEDHOOKPROC + $E757
[0DBB1FCA]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at POSTEDHOOKPROC + $1246
[0DBB2924]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at POSTEDHOOKPROC + $1BA0
[0DBB2753]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at POSTEDHOOKPROC + $19CF
[0DB7E60C]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $3794
[0DB7E634]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $37BC
[0DB88DDF]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $DF67
[0DB9C6C0]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $21848
[0DBA10D2]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $2625A
[0DB9CF1C]{bordbk180N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $220A4
[5016EDDD]{rtl180.bpl  } System.Classes.TComponent.UpdateAction (Line 16030, "System.Classes.pas" + 1) + $A
[5057C69F]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.ProcessUpdate (Line 7244, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $11
[5005EE12]{rtl180.bpl  } System.@IsClass (Line 15664, "System.pas" + 1) + $8
[5057C708]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TraverseClients3 (Line 7261, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 5) + $1E
[5016EDDD]{rtl180.bpl  } System.Classes.TComponent.UpdateAction (Line 16030, "System.Classes.pas" + 1) + $A
[5057C69F]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.ProcessUpdate (Line 7244, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $11
[5005EE12]{rtl180.bpl  } System.@IsClass (Line 15664, "System.pas" + 1) + $8
[5057C713]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TraverseClients3 (Line 7261, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 5) + $29
[5057C722]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TraverseClients3 (Line 7261, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 5) + $38
[5016EDDD]{rtl180.bpl  } System.Classes.TComponent.UpdateAction (Line 16030, "System.Classes.pas" + 1) + $A
[50455D4A]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.GetControl (Line 9131, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 4) + $A
[5005EE12]{rtl180.bpl  } System.@IsClass (Line 15664, "System.pas" + 1) + $8
[5016EDDD]{rtl180.bpl  } System.Classes.TComponent.UpdateAction (Line 16030, "System.Classes.pas" + 1) + $A
[5057C69F]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.ProcessUpdate (Line 7244, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $11
[5005EE12]{rtl180.bpl  } System.@IsClass (Line 15664, "System.pas" + 1) + $8
[5057C708]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TraverseClients3 (Line 7261, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 5) + $1E
[5057C722]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TraverseClients3 (Line 7261, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 5) + $38
(00037999){CnWizards_DXE4.dll} [0E048999]
(00037A00){CnWizards_DXE4.dll} [0E048A00]
(00037AB1){CnWizards_DXE4.dll} [0E048AB1]
[50455D4A]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.GetControl (Line 9131, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 4) + $A
(000352F2){CnWizards_DXE4.dll} [0E0462F2]
(00263348){mmx_bds11.dll} [0F204348]
[500630C0]{rtl180.bpl  } System.@FinalizeArray (Line 29800, "System.pas" + 139) + $0
[500630B0]{rtl180.bpl  } System.@FinalizeArray (Line 29788, "System.pas" + 127) + $0
[50580E8F]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 10290, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 25) + $1
[50580ECA]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage (Line 10318, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[50581205]{vcl180.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 10456, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 26) + $3
```

Comment: _Explain what you mean by "does not work"?_ (Doesn't stop on breakpoint? Cannot be set? Not matching correct lines in code?) One thing you have not mentioned in things that you've tried: Have you checked if any code is explicitly disabling debug info? The project setting can be overridden by `{$D-}` or `{$DEBUGINFO OFF}`. Also make sure you aren't referencing different copies of the same unit. This can lead to a situation where breakpints seem to be in the wrong place.

Comment: Do you also done Option>Delphi Complier>Compling>Use debug .dcus = True. Also clean the project and then compile.

Comment: Is this mainly one unit, or several? Have you ensured that the unit line endings are all CRLF and not LF or CR (happens when pasting code from webpage or help file sometimes).

Comment: @CraigYoung, I mean the IDE never stops at the breakpoints. I've updated my question.

Comment: @Ravaut123, Yes, I've tried that.

Comment: Your project is a dll library?

Comment: @MikeD, so after I read your comment, I tried more breakpoints, and found that breakpoints work with another unit (which is called earlier in the execution stream)! And have encountered some unexpected stops at the CPU window... I will do more test and report back the details.

Comment: @Ravaut123, yes, it's a DLL project, and the host is Word 2010 32bit, my OS is Win 7 64bit.

Comment: Can you call the dll from a new project. Like a button that's call the dll. Or is the dll registrated?

Comment: @Ravaut123, it's an in-process ActiveX server, so yes, it's being registered as a Word addon.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain there isn't a bug in your code preventing you from reaching the line in question? It may be an erratic bug meaning that sometimes you get there, and sometimes you don't. (One common source for such bugs is uninitialised variables.)

Comment: @CraigYoung, that's the first thing I'll be checking, thanks for the hint!

Comment: PS: Based on you most recent edit: I count swallowing an exception without you being aware of it as a bug. ;) You've probably recently enabled "Notify on language exceptions". Previously you were getting the exception (but unaware of it). This prevented you from reaching the line of code with the breakpoint. (_I.e. They were working all along._)

Comment: @CraigYoung, it's a very very significant change of the entire source during the D7-XE4 upgrade, so it's possible ;) Thanks very much and I'll be checking and report back here.

Comment: Option>Delphi Complier>Compling>Assertions set to false and back to true

Comment: @CraigYoung, suddenly, without any changes to the source or settings, just a rebuild of the project, today the breakpoint at the same point became working, and the above mentioned AV's no more appearing... Strange!

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself - it seems that it's the `DBugIntf.pas` from GExperts causing some strange error. After disabling it, the breakpoints in my IDE has been working in an basically-acceptable manner - if it stops working, a restart of the IDE will fix it. Thanks all for the help.